# question about the length of strings in java

Tags: java, string

I got a question about the Strings in Java:

```
new String(array, 0, end)
```

here, I don't know why we use 'end' instead of end-1? I mean, the array I want to store(0, end - 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `String.java`, you could see that the third parameter is `count`

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count)

value[] - input char array
offset - from which position you want the chars to be copied
count - number of chars to copy
```

So if you have a char[] of size 10, you could create a string as follows

```
new String(input, 0, 10); // NOT new String(input, 0, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you misunderstood the use of the count feature, your question does raise a feature that is common throughout Java and other languages as well.  Most ranges go from `a to b` where `a` is inclusive and `b` is exclusive.

The following example, albeit contrived, shows how this can help.

`String.substring()` is one such example:

Notice subsequent calls of substring use the previous ending index as the start of the next.  This makes it easy to think about concatentating strings.

```java
      String str = "encyclopedia";
      String newstr1 =
            str.substring(0, 3) + str.substring(3, 6) + str.substring(6);
      String newstr2 =
            str.substring(0, 2) + str.substring(2, 4) + str.substring(4);

      System.out.println(str);
      System.out.println(newstr1);
      System.out.println(newstr2);
```

All three print statement print `encyclopedia`

Comment: I don’t understand why newstr1 and newstr2 also print the whole strings encyclopedia.

Comment: First, if you didn't know, the `+` is concatenation.  For the substrings, consider `abcd`.  `substring(0,2)` is `ab` (the last index is excluded).  But `substring(2,4)` is `cd`.  The string is length `4` but the index of the last character is `3`.  The best way see this is to print out the individual strings of both examples prior to concatenation.